# NoMethodError 'title_url' when posting json to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

real code:

```
class TitlesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def create
    title = Title.create!(params[:title])
    respond_with title
  end
end
```

spec:

```
describe TitlesController do
  it 'receives a json response' do
    post :create, title: { name: 'fancy title'}, format: 'json'
    expect(controller).to respond_with(201)
  end
end
```

==>
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `title_url' for #

Why in the world is this trying to call title_url??????

Comment: Find out if you are using `title_url` somewhere in your code base. Run `grep -rin "title_url" *`

Comment: @patrick, I am not sure. but try passing the format as a symbol in your test. Also make sure that the format is passed as `json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you respond with a resource, `title` in this case, for a post request it will redirect to the show action. From the [`respond_with` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with):

> If there are no errors, i.e. the resource was saved successfully, the response redirect's to the resource i.e. its show action.

To get the URL for the show action it will call `title_url(title)`

You can override this redirect behaviour by specifying a `:location` (covered in the Customizing response behaviour section of the docs):

```
respond_with title, location: some_other_url
```

Comment: @Shadewell: doesn't it redirect to `show` only in case of `html` request?

Comment: Hmm, actually, not the man, @Vimsha is right. That behaviour is only for `html` requests. For json requests it should just render the json representation of the title.

Comment: no.. you the man.  I added location: nil to my test and it passes now...  so, it's official, you the man.